# Allow element to be from one complexType AND/OR another

Tags: xml, xsd, enumeration, complextype

I have a an element `tag` which has a complex type consisting of `name`, `operator` and `value`;
where `name` is one of "GENRE", "ALBUM" or "ARTIST" (simplified) and should allow the following `operators`: "EQ" (equals), "CS" (contains) or "SW" (startsWith) (simplified).

Now there is the `tag` with `name` "YEAR" which has integer value, not String as all others and should therefor be allowed only the operators "LT" (less) and "GT" (greater) (simplified).

I am not able to build this conditions into my existing XSD, as it is not allowed to have more than one complexType within one element. So I can catch collisions at first when processing them in my java routines which is a bit late. I want the XML-Validator to "cry out" the misformed XML as early as possible.

Here is an extract of my XSD schema:

```
<xs:element name="tags" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="PLAYLISTS" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="GENRE" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="ALBUM" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="ARTIST" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="ALBUM_ARTIST" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="YEAR" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="TITLE" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="COMMENT" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="EQ" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="CS" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="SW" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="EW" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="LT" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="GT" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here is a sample extract of a XML, where the first two tag-elements should be valid, and the last ones should NOT be valid. Because an integer-operator was used for a String-value respectively a string-operator was used for an int-value.

```
<tags>
    <tag>
        <name>ALBUM</name>
        <operator>CS</operator>
        <value>The</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>YEAR</name>
        <operator>LT</operator>
        <value>2010</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>ALBUM</name>
        <operator>GT</operator>
        <value>The</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>YEAR</name>
        <operator>CS</operator>
        <value>2010</value>
    </tag>
</tags>
```

I hope my problem is understandable for you and you can help me out with a suitable solution - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should know that you can only realize this with XSD-1.1, because the `xs:assert` function is needed. So, to restrict your `tag` elements with a `name` child with the value `YEAR`, you have to set this restriction after the corresponding `</xs:sequence>` element of your `<tag>` definition:

```
<xs:assert test="name!='YEAR' or (name='YEAR' and value castable as xs:integer and (operator='LT' or operator='GT'))" />
```

This assertion restricts your `<tag>` elements to those whose `<name>` child doesn't have a value of "YEAR", and those whose `<name>` child does have a value of "YEAR" and a `<value>` of the type `xs:integer` and an `<operator>` child of the value "LT" or "GT". Be careful with the AND/OR in this case, **because the assertion needs to be TRUE for all** `<tag>`s, hence the `or`.

Your complete XSD file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.1">
    <xs:element name="tags">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="tag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="PLAYLISTS" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="GENRE" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="ALBUM" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="ARTIST" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="ALBUM_ARTIST" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="YEAR" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="TITLE" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="COMMENT" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="EQ" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="CS" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="SW" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="EW" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="LT" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="GT" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:assert test="name!='YEAR' or (name='YEAR' and value castable as xs:integer and (operator='LT' or operator='GT'))" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Another way of restricting the `<tag>` elements is

```
<xs:assert test="(name!='YEAR' and (operator!='LT' or operator!='GT')) or (name='YEAR' and value castable as xs:integer and (operator='LT' or operator='GT'))" />
```

It also excludes the operators `LT` and `GT` from all elements except `YEAR`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and enlightning answer!

Although I have changed to version "1.1" the validator still keeps saying "Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced or occurs too often".

I think, there are missing some '$' too, but this seems not to be the actual problem, as typing "<xs:assert" is already causing the error.

Comment: Unfortunately Eclipse (2019-3) seems not able to handle XML Schema version 1.1 - only 1.0 :-(

Comment: Then you're probably out of luck with your restrictions.